# How can I iterate over array elements matching a regular expression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a method that can be used with "each" to filter array elements depending on a regular expression matching?

I have for example the following array:

```
arr = ["one", "has_two", "has_tree", "four"]
```

I want to loop into this array and to take only elements beginning with "has".

the following code is doing the loop for all the elements

```
arr.each |element| do

....

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable's `grep` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001482) to do this:

```
arr.grep(/^has/).each do |element|
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [`select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000251) the elements you're interested in, and then loop over those:

```
arr.select { |e| e[/^has/] }.each do |element|


end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say:

```
arr.find_all{|el| el =~ /^has/}.each do...
```